# Can cookies identify a website exit time?

Tags: html, cookies, web

Is it possible using cookies to determine the time a user left a webpage if its the last one visited? In other words, if a user visits 5 webpages on my website, can I determine the time the user left page 5 to go to a new website? And does it matter if the user shuts down the browser and doesn't visit a new website? Can we detect this using cookies or an alternate means?

Comment: How do you expect the cookies to be transmitted to your site if there is no further interaction from the browser?

Comment: You cannot use cookies, but you may be able to do this with JavaScript/AJAX - provided you don't want to use google analytics or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are read and written when a user accesses your site. There is no cookie-based way to initiate communication when a user is no longer on your site.

As noted in the comments, you should use analytics (such as Google Analytics, Omniture or others) to gather data about exiting users.

Comment: I took a seminar recently on Google Analytics and the instructor said that Google can determine when you exit a website. I started thinking about this and I'm lost for how this is possible, unless the next site you visit is also a Google Analytics site, in which case Google would know where you were before.

Comment: According to [this page](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565?hl=en), GA sets a cookie with a 30-minute expiration each time a visitor loads one of your pages. If the 30 minutes expires without another page load by that visitor, GA knows that he left.

Answer (score 0):

You could use javascript to sent times to a server on page load and exit. Support for onunload() is very bad though http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onunload.asp. I wouldn't use it.

A expensive way to do it would be to make an ajax call to to your server every few seconds (or whatever) and see when they stop coming.

```
setInterval( function(){

    imHere();

}, 2000 );

function imHere(){

    $.post('script.php', {some: data});

}
```

That would be nasty though. Much better to use google analytics.